# A probabilistic interpretation of the following monotonicity?

Tags: probability

Suppose ${\bf e}_k$ is the $k$'th basis vector and $P$ is a stochastic matrix. Then
$$ \|({\bf e}_i - {\bf e}_j)^T P^l\|_1 $$ is nonincreasing in $l$. This is just a consequence of the fact that the matrix $1$-norm is equal to the largest among the column sums. This fact seems like it should have a probabilistic interpretation. Does it?

Comment: It does. Are you familiar with the coupling method?

Comment: Somewhat familiar with coupling, yes. Please do explain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\|({\mathbf e}_i - {\mathbf e}_j)^T P^\ell\|_1=\min_{(X,Y)} \Pr[X_\ell\ne Y_\ell],
$$
where the minimum is over all the Markov chains $X=(X_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ and $Y=(Y_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ of transition matrix $P$ such that $X_0=i$ and $Y_0=j$ almost surely. Now, one has the freedom to build $X_{\ell+1}$ and $Y_{\ell+1}$ at will from $X_{\ell}$ and $Y_{\ell}$, as long as the transitions are given by $P$. Thus...